WPA supplicant eapol issues not connecting to a remote host WPA Enterprise
Trying to connect to a remote host, however I am receiving an error message shown below:
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED

My connection config file is shown below:
p2p_disabled=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=root
network={
    ssid="VERY"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="my\admin"
    password="admin"
    ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}

This is how I connect to interface
wpa_supplicant -B -i <wlfan123> -c <config file>

I have found that it hints to a driver issue.. Is there any alternative to using wpa_supplicant native to kali.
